# Casting to Int returns different value than FloorToInt for positive number in c#

Tags: c#, casting, floor

[Edit] I rewrote the whole example as told by the comments.

```
    float value = 0.52631580f;

    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        float division = sum / value;
        int result = (int)division;

        Console.WriteLine(division.ToString("0.00000") + " - " + result.ToString("0.00000"));
        sum += value;
    }
```

The results are not the ones expected:

```
0,00000 - 0,00000
1,00000 - 1,00000
2,00000 - 2,00000
3,00000 - 3,00000
4,00000 - 4,00000
5,00000 - 5,00000
6,00000 - 5,00000 <---- It should be 6
7,00000 - 7,00000
```

If I do it manually,  (int)6.00000000000f  <-- Returns 6, of course.

How is that possible?

Comment: Do we have to guess what `sampleSize.x` is, or what the value being cast, truncated or rounded is? Casting doesn't mean truncating.

Comment: if `posX` is a `float` why are you casting it to `float` in the first calculation?

Comment: Casting a float to int doesn't truncate the fractional parts. It *rounds* the number with half-way numbers [rounding to the closest even number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Single_). This actually *reduces the statistical error* as each time, the error is +0.5 or -0.5 which over time averages to 0. If truncation was used, the error would be +0.5 always. This is actually the [*default rounding mode* in IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)

Comment: So to `How is that possible?` the answer is `that's the standard`. You can specify different rounding rules if you want, eg round to even, away from zero, towards zero. In signal and image processing applications though, rounding/truncating is essentially noise. Round-to-even eliminates that noise. Floor/ceiling maximize it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry. I just modified the text so that it's clear. I didn't know any of those details you give me . Maybe that should be the answer to this question if you want to add it. I'll study it a little bit. In case you add it as the answer, then I'll mark it correct!

Comment: @juharr Sorry, I forgot to remove that. I was testing. I cleared it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, casting float to int *does* truncate towards 0. See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/c1e33e772cab1f57aad421925887d00f for example.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos By the way, I was reading the article and... most of the methods affect how to round the negative numbers. My floatValue1 is always positive. That's why I moved my FloorToInt to an (int) which somebody that uses that a lot told me that it worked the same as the floorToInt for positive numbers...   The error... that's another thing that could be affecting, though.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you could provide a [mcve]. Yes, we could build it ourselves from what you've shown us, but it's a waste of effort for multiple people to do that when *you* can give us something we can copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh yes, I know but I thought this example was pretty basic. I was just wondering if somebody knew something about casting to int that I didn't know. I'll try to do that. Thanks

Comment: Actually we *can't* reproduce it at the moment as you haven't told us what `floatValue2` is. Please don't make us guess.

Comment: @JonSkeet oops. I followed the documentation before answering [Single.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.system-iconvertible-toint32?view=net-5.0) to [Convert.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Single_) which specifies round-to-even, even using the question's numbers. But `(int)3.5` returns 3, not 4.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok. I created a mimnimal example. I could reproduce the same in a small piece of code. Hope it helps!

Comment: No, that isn't a complete example. We want something to copy, paste, compile and run. We shouldn't have to mess around adding a Main method and calling the method multiple times. I'd expect you to already *have* such a console app - so please provide it. You're asking for help - so make it as *easy* as possible for us to help you.

Comment: Print the raw value of `division` in each iteration, using `Console.WriteLine(division.ToString("G16"))`. You should find the results enlightening as to what happens with floating-point precision on repeated operations. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4137916).

Comment: @JeroenMostert bet you thought about the .NET Core 3 change too? In this case the difference appears at 6 digits though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry about that. I don't know how to write a console app. I work with Unity, which is a game development engine that uses a different syntax for the rest of the code. But I get the idea from the different answsers I got. Thanks

Comment: @darkgaze: No, Unity doesn't use a different syntax. Sure, it's generally a different environment, but the C# syntax is the same. I would strongly recommend that you learn how to create console apps - it won't take long, and you'll save a *lot* of time in the long run.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is right. And standard compliant. I changed the `WriteLine` line to this :

```
Console.WriteLine($"{sum:0.000} {value:0.000} {division:N18} - {result:0.00000}");
```

And got

```
2.105 0.526 4.000000000000000000 - 4.00000
2.632 0.526 5.000000000000000000 - 5.00000
3.158 0.526 5.999999523162841797 - 5.00000 
3.684 0.526 6.999999523162841797 - 6.00000 
4.211 0.526 7.999999046325683594 - 7.00000 
4.737 0.526 8.999999046325683594 - 8.00000
```

Rounding errors mean the division result isn't exactly 6, 7 or 8. With just 5 digits, I get:

```
3.158 0.526 6.00000 - 5.00000 
3.684 0.526 7.00000 - 6.00000 
4.211 0.526 8.00000 - 7.00000 
4.737 0.526 9.00000 - 8.00000
```

This isn't about how C# truncates or rounds, it's about how floating point numbers are formatted. The IEEE compliant way is to *round* to the desired precision when formatting.

Phew - for a moment, I actually forgot what I knew about floats.

PS: there's another funny [change at 15 digits](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) that was introduced in .NET Core 3. Before that, string formatting stopped producing digits at 15 digits which lead to quite a bit of confusion with values that were close but not quite equal to an integer.

Since .NET Core 3, the string formatter emits enough digits to produce `the shortest roundtrippable string`. Using

```
Console.WriteLine($"{division} - {result}");
```

Produces :

```
4 - 4
 5 - 5 
5.9999995 - 5 
6.9999995 - 6 
7.999999 - 7 
8.999999 - 8
```

Which is why they teach us in computing math to **never** compare floats for equality, but only check whether the absolute difference is below a threshold.

Something I *always* forget and have to rediscover after crashes or infinite loops.

**PPS: Rounding errors**

The fractional digits are produced because `float` doesn't have enough precision to store either `sum` or `division` without rounding.

Using `$"{sum} {division} - {result}"` and switching from `float` to `double` produces only one result with fractional digits:

```
3.1578948 6 - 6
 3.6842105999999997 6.999999999999999 - 6 
4.2105264 8 - 8
```

Notice that even `sum` has rounding errors.

Only `decimal` has enough precision to store an accurate result and avoid rounding errors:

```
2.63157900 5 - 5
 3.15789480 6 - 6 
3.68421060 7 - 7 
4.21052640 8 - 8 
4.73684220 9 - 9
```